# Remove character starting with x and ending with x and everything between it in a string

Tags: python, string

**The problem:** I want to remove a specific code within a question. The code changes position from question to question so I cannot rely on the position of the code to remove it.

Here is what it looks like:

> Now thinking specifically about the home improvement brand _Everest<.br/>On a scale of 0 to 10, where 0 is "Not at all familiar/ knowledgeable" and 10 is "Very familiar/ knowledgeable", how familiar / knowledgeable do you consider yourself to be with..."

The code - `<.br>` - is always attached to the word before and after.

**Solution:** I would like to know how, if there is a function, to delete/remove a set of characters which start with x and end with x and removes everything between it.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

def remove_between_anchors(text, anchor):
    return re.sub(r'{0}.+?{0}'.format(anchor), '', text)

remove_between_anchors('123aa456aa789', 'aa') # returns '123789'
```

**EDIT**: if the start/end anchors are different:

```
def remove_between_anchors(text, start, end):
    return re.sub(r'{0}.+?{1}'.format(start, end), '', text)

remove_between_anchors('123<abc>456', '<', '>') # returns '123456'
```

Comment: I used this function and there is one minor problem, the start x is different to the end x - '<' '>'. It would've worked if both the start x and the end x were the same - '<' '<'. Any solution?

Comment: Perfect! the edited version worked a treat. Much appreciated eumiro.