# string remove between start string and end string

Tags: php

I find this concept is the same as what I need:-

[Remove character starting with x and ending with x and everything between it in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334442/remove-character-starting-with-x-and-ending-with-x-and-everything-between-it-in)

would there be similar function in php? also, is it possible to do replace all such cases in a long string?

example:
$text = "
`<h2 class="active" tabindex="0" rel="120">Title 2</h2><h2 class="active" tabindex="0" list="20" rel="120">Title 2</h2><h2 class="active" tabindex="0" rel="120">Title 2</h2>`";

Here, I wish to detect class="active", and the ">" of `</h2>`, the remove any changing contents between.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking the question? This should be in every PHP textbook and tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in PHP is something like this:

```
function remove_between($str, $anchor)
{
    $anchor = preg_quote($anchor, '/');

    return preg_replace("/$anchor(.*)$anchor/U", '', $str);
}

remove_between('123aa456aa789', 'aa'); // 123789
```

Comment: if the start and end strings are different, shall I add more more $anchor?